# How To Debug Custom Feedback Form Sidebar Slider JavaScript Error?

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript

I'm trying to create a Feedback form Sidebar slider.

Workout:

step 1:

C:\wamp\www\magento\app\design\frontend\default\theme327k\layout\local.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
<default>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/mrova-feedback-form.css</name></action>
        <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/mrova-feedback-form.js</name></action>
       <!-- <action method="addJs"><script>/js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js</script></action>  -->
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="core/template" name="feedback.box" template="html/feedbackbox.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</default>
</layout>
```

step 2:

C:\wamp\www\magento\app\design\frontend\default\theme327k\template\html\feedbackbox.phtml

```
   <div id="mrova-feedback" style="margin-top: -225.5px; top: 50%; display: block; height: 451px; right: -420px;     z-index: 66666;">
        <div id="mrova-contact-thankyou" style="display: none;">
            Thank you.  We'hv received your feedback.
        </div>
        <div id="mrova-form">
            <form id="mrova-contactform" action="feedbackbox.phtml" method="post">
                <ul >
                    <li>
                        <label for="mrova-name">Your Name*</label> <input type="text" name="mrova-name" class="required" id="mrova-name" value="">
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label for="mrova-email">Email*</label> <input type="text" name="mrova-email" class="required" id="mrova-email" value="">
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label for="mrova-message">Message*</label>
                        <textarea class="required" id="mrova-message" name="mrova-message"  rows="8" cols="30"></textarea>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <input type="submit" value="Send" id="mrova-sendbutton" name="mrova-sendbutton">
            </form>
        </div>
        <div id="mrova-img-control"></div>
    </div>


<?php
header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');

if (isset($_GET["mrova-name"])) {
    $name = strip_tags($_GET['mrova-name']);
    $email = strip_tags($_GET['mrova-email']);
    $message = strip_tags($_GET['mrova-message']);
    $header = "From: ". $name . " <" . $email . ">"; 

    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $httpref = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
    $httpagent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
    $today = date("F j, Y, g:i a");    
    $recipient = 'abc@gmail.com';
    $subject = 'Contact Form';
    $mailbody = "
First Name: $name
Email: $email
Message: $message
IP: $ip
Browser info: $httpagent
Referral: $httpref
Sent: $today
";
    $result = 'success';

    if (mail($recipient, $subject, $mailbody, $header)) {
        echo json_encode($result);
    }
}
?>
```

step 3:

C:\wamp\www\magento\skin\frontend\default\theme327k\css\mrova-feedback-form.css

```css
label {
    display:block; 
    padding-bottom:5px; 
    margin-top:20px;
}

#mrova-feedback{
    display: hidden;
    width: 420px;
    position: fixed;
    right: -462px;
    border: 1px solid #3cb58c;
    padding: 8px 20px;
    background-color: #fff;
}

#mrova-contactform ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#mrova-contactform input, #mrova-contactform textarea{
    width: 400px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

#mrova-contactform ul li {
    list-style:none; 
    padding-bottom:20px;
}

#mrova-img-control{
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    left: -52px;
    width: 52px;
    background: transparent url('http://192.168.1.65/magento/feedback.jpg');
    height: 168px;
}

#mrova-contactform #mrova-sendbutton {
    width:60px;
    background:#db4f4a; color:#fff; 
    cursor:pointer;
    padding:5px 10px; 
    border: none;
}
```

step 4:

C:\wamp\www\magento\skin\frontend\default\theme327k\js\mrova-feedback-form.js

```
    (function ($) {
$.fn.vAlign = function() {
    return this.each(function(i){
    var h = $(this).height();
    var oh = $(this).outerHeight();
    var mt = (h + (oh - h)) / 2;    
    $(this).css("margin-top", "-" + mt + "px"); 
    $(this).css("top", "50%");
    }); 
};
$.fn.toggleClick = function(){
    var functions = arguments ;
    return this.click(function(){
            var iteration = $(this).data('iteration') || 0;
            functions[iteration].apply(this, arguments);
            iteration = (iteration + 1) % functions.length ;
            $(this).data('iteration', iteration);
    });
};
})(jQuery);
(function($) {
    $(window).load(function(event) {

//cache
    $img_control = $("#mrova-img-control");
    $mrova_feedback = $('#mrova-feedback');
    $mrova_contactform = $('#mrova-contactform');

    //setback to block state and vertical align to center
    $mrova_feedback.vAlign()
    .css({'display':'block','height':$mrova_feedback.outerHeight()});
    //Aligning feedback button to center with the parent div 

    $img_control.vAlign()
    //animate the form
    .toggleClick(function(){
        $mrova_feedback.animate({'right':'-2px'},1000);
    }, function(){
        $mrova_feedback.animate({'right':'-'+$mrova_feedback.outerWidth()},1000);
    });

    //Form handling
    $('#mrova-sendbutton').click( function() {
                var url = 'feedbackbox.phtml';
                var error = 0;



                $('.required', $mrova_contactform).each(function(i) {
                    if($(this).val() === '') {
                        error++;
                    }
                });
                // each
                if(error > 0) {
                    alert('Please fill in all the mandatory fields. Mandatory fields are marked with an asterisk *.');
                } else {
                    $str = $mrova_contactform.serialize();

                    //submit the form
                    $.ajax({
                        type : "GET",
                        url : url,
                        data : $str,
                        success : function(data) {

                            if(data == 'success') {
                                // show thank you
                                $('#mrova-contact-thankyou').show();
                                $mrova_contactform.hide();
                            } else {
                                alert('Unable to send your message. Please try again.');
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    //$.ajax

                }
                return false;
            });

});

})(jQuery);
```

console error :

[image]
How can I solve this issue?

how can i solve the error?

Answer (score 0):

You can't set **`feedbackbox.phtml`** as **`url`**. You need to set controller action URL as **`var url`** to fix the problem.

Please check C:\wamp\www\magento\skin\frontend\default\theme327k\js\mrova-feedback-form.js:

```
$('#mrova-sendbutton').click( function() {
var url = 'feedbackbox.phtml';
```

and change the value of url.

Comment: After change the var url = url;  the mail received but the response like "Unable to send your message. Please try again" but i received mail. How can i solve this error?

Comment: Any idea about this error? showing "Unable to send your message. Please try again" instead of showing Success message.

Comment: @zus, This is because after sending the email, you should return **`success`**, but you are returning it within json_encode() function.

Comment: the success message show like : https://snag.gy/ZV4jRG.jpg

Comment: Okay, how can i  alter my code? i need to display success message on the same slide-bar.

Comment: Just remove or comment this line: **`$mrova_contactform.hide();`**

Comment: not working...showing "Unable to send your message. Please try again. instead of success message.

Comment: FYI - Email service working, only the error is success message.

Comment: Any idea? @Mohit

Comment: FYI https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84115/discussion-between-zus-and-prince  -- last few messages @Mohit

Comment: I am just new in CSS, how to move feedback tab from right to left bottom? @Mohit Kumar Arora